# angular 2 from scratch without npm

Tags: angular

I have looked into the Angular 2 quick start and overview online from [here](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/setup.html#!#install-node)

But, I cannot find more information on doing the same quickstart without npm.

I would like to understand where and how the angular2 libraries are referenced into the project.

Can someone point me out?

Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

You cannot use angular2 without npm. First of all there is (for so far I know) no other source than npm for downloading angular2 core source to get started. besides of that it will be a hell of a job because all the dependend third party modules you want to add must be added manually and if there are updates, including for angular2 it self, it will be harder to manage, check for updates and update all of them.

To understand where and how the angular2 libraries are referenced I will suggest to start from index.html (if you have used angular-cli, see quickstart code at github: https://github.com/angular/quickstart). there are some js files added to head section and the script starts with `System.import('app').catch(function(err){ console.error(err); });` where it begins.

Comment: Is it not possible to just reference the libraries from angular that are used by  me from google's cdn like we use jquery? Is it necessary to host all of those files along with my site?

Comment: if you don't use typescript or dart it is possible because at the end its all javascript. To do that it will take a lot of time to get all code etc. besides of that npm is only a package manager. To compare with cdn, npm grabs the most recent source which is managed in package.json instead of adding a link to somewhere on the web. I think this should not hinder to investigate angular2.

Comment: You can absolutely use Angular without npm. They actually recommend you use a CDN.

Comment: @AndréDion - If you read also the comments I don't say it is not absolutly possible to use npm, but why would you make it thougher for yourself to search for all dependencies by not using npm? btw instead of adding this to comments I would suggest you to post an answer how it should be done so Josh and also I could learn. Could you also post where they suggest to use CDN because I  can't find it their documentation?